# Endogeneity and Simultaneity Issues with Independent Variables

Tags: endogeneity, simultaneous-equation

One potential source for biased OLS coefficients is simultaneity (i.e. y and x are simultaneously determined). However, will the OLS coefficients also be biased if my independent (x) variables are simultaneously determined?

Formally, I want to test whether increasing foreign direct investments (X1) is associated with emissions increases (Y), and if this relationship holds to a lesser extent in countries with good governance (X2).

However, empirical research found that foreign direct investments (X1) can also lower the quality of governance (X2). Additionally, the quality of governance (X2) determines how much foreign direct investments there are (X1).

So there is some kind of simultaneity between the independent variables. However, it is unlike the textbook examples where X and Y are simultaneously determined. I don´t know whether my situation also leads to biased estimators? Maybe somebody knows where I can find further information on this?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it "just" refers to the situation in which your regressors are correlated, and that has no impact on unbiasedness of the estimators. Strongly correlated regressors lead to less precise estimators, however.

Comment: Thank you Cristohph! I read up on that and I get your point.